# Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly

Tags: android, flutter, google-mobile-ads

Not sure why but I am getting this when trying to start the app on an emulator

[image]

Also this is what is setup in project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

And here is the initialize code:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `meta-data` tag is not getting recognized. You should have the meta-data tag for ads outside of the `activity` tag and within the `application` tag

Comment: If I could kiss you right now I would. Thank you kind stranger, that solved the issue!

Comment: I'm glad that solves your issue. Happy coding :)